Execute Python with Powershell in SQL Server 2019
I have been using SQL Server 2016's SQL Server Agent with bottom setting and script for last 3+ years. It was/is working fine.

But, now, I am migrating everything to SQL Server 2019, but the same command does not work.
So, I am wondering if there is anything that I have to modify (in terms of script) because I am using SQL Server 2019.
When I use SQL Server Agent to run other Powershell script (which executes something within Powershell), it works.
When I run the Powershell now, and I am getting this error message:


Have you looked at this? https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/jfrcyt/how_to_execute_python_from_a_sql_agent_job/

@JonathanFite What does it mean by "you should use a Proxy to run Python just like you would SSIS"?

What's the error message?

@J.Mini Please see the updated post with error mesage. Actually, when I just ran the Powershell file which executes Python file, I see the error on the top. It appears that SQL Server Agent is now out of scope. So strange.

@J.Mini I think this might be the solution but I am not sure how to go about doing it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933225/3842845

@Java You're screwed. I've had similar problems on my own box. Unless you can grant the group policy that allows impersonation, then your only choice is to make the account a full Admin. Talk to your Windows people.

@J.Mini What does "allowing impersonation" mean? Is some set up wrong on the box? I  would like to know the right phrase to fix the situation.

@Java I'm afraid that I don't recall the fine details.

If you're not going to specify the program to run the .py file, you need Windows to have a default for that file type.  Instead, specify the python executable/binary.
This would be an example of what your final line should be, but you'll need to edit it to point to your python binary:
Start-Process C:\Path\To\Python\Executable\python.exe "$cmd"


It appears that it is working (with modifying the line), but don't I have to fix the original issue with some type of AD or group policy?

Are you getting an additional error?  If so, what is it?

I do not see error now (by modifying that line). It is working. But, I am not sure whether I need to fix any set up in AD (for later).

That'll depend on whether you're using a different AD account for the SQL Agent than you were before.

So, it is not like a major issue, but only affecting AD account for the "SQL Agent" then, I guess.
